# Averaging untill an index value that corresponds with the value of another array in Numpy

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization, array-broadcasting, numpy-slicing

I have one array in which the values should be averaged until the day that is given as a value in another array. The first array has 365 days as the first axis, and the second array corresponds to specific julian dates, ranging from 0 to 365, from which the value from the first array should be averaged.

```
array1.shape = (365, 375, 700)
array2.shape = (375, 700)
```

The resultant array naturally will have the same shape as the second array that is used for averaging the first array. Is there an easy way to do this? Maybe with some for loops or with vectorization/broadcasting?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.cumsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html?highlight=cumsum#numpy.cumsum) to calculate the cumulative sum along `axis=0` then taking some index and dividing by this index give the average till this index.

```
import numpy as np


def averages(a, b):
    return a.cumsum(axis=0)[
        b.ravel(),
        np.repeat(np.arange(b.shape[0]), b.shape[1]),
        np.tile(np.arange(b.shape[1]), b.shape[0]),
    ].reshape(b.shape) / (b + 1)


a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 2, 2)
b = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 2]])
print(a)
# [[[ 0  1]
#   [ 2  3]]

#  [[ 4  5]
#   [ 6  7]]

#  [[ 8  9]
#   [10 11]]]
print(b)
# [[0 1]
#  [1 2]]
print(averages(a, b))
# [[0. 3.]
#  [4. 7.]]
```